# Set focus on scrollbox on pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a scrollbox similar to:

http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_scroll_box.cfm

Right now, you have to click inside it after the page loads in order to use arrow keys to go up and down. I'd like it to be so that on page load, the focus is inside it already so you don't have to click inside it to use arrow keys. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need exactly. Note that there are a few key things playing here. First the body of the document needs to have the "onload" property calling your small simple script for "Focus".  And the only change that I made to your code is the addition of an "id" property to the div.  You can change this to suit your needs.

Enjoy!

```
<body  onload="Focus()">
<div id="myDiv" style="height:120px;width:120px;border:1px solid #ccc;font:16px/26px Georgia, Garamond, Serif;overflow:auto;">
As you can see, once there's enough text in this box, the box will grow scroll bars... that's why we call it a scroll box! You could also place an image into the scroll box.
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function Focus()
 {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").focus();
 }
 </script>
 </body>
```

You can see this working by simply copying this code onto a brand new text file and save it with an .html extension.  Then double click on it and it should open up in any of your browsers. Provided you have scripting enabled then it should scroll just fine.

Comment: This is perfect, but is there a way to get rid of the dotted selection on first load?

Answer (score 4):

the `div` is not focusable element so the focus function will not work probably, add `tabindex` attribute to your `div` to make focus function work fine.

```
<div id="yourDivID" tabindex="-1"></div
```

Depending on the value given to `tabindex`, it will behave differently:

- 0 will allow you to focus the element with the keyboard arrows and tab key
- -1 will disable tabbing, but it will still be focusable
- Anything greater then 0 will allow you prioratize tab focusing, where 1 has the highest priority

now you can use focus in the div
if you want to use Jquery

```
$("#yourDivID").focus();
```

if you want to use JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("yourDivID").focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

On DOM ready, simply set the focus:

```
$("#yourTextboxID").focus();
```